# Pasting 2 single column csv files together generates blank cells

Tags: csv, unix, paste

I thought this problem would be simple using the paste command.

Imagine you have two single column files like these:

**file1.csv**

```
A

B

C
```

**file2.csv**

```
D

E

F
```

**Desired result after paste:**

```
A,D

B,E

C,F
```

Tried the following:  `paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv > output.csv`

Unfortunately, output.csv looks like the following (the _ character represents a blank field).  In other words, blank "cells" are introduced into the original column from file1.  In other words, there are twice as many rows are there should be, and blanks in the first column corresponding to the file2 data that appears in column 2.

```
A  

__D

B  

__E

C  

__F
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess you got one, or more, of the files from a nasty Windows box and it contains superfluous carriage returns as well as linefeeds. Try cleaning your input files with `tr -d '\r' < file1.csv > cleanfile1.csv` and likewise `file2.csv`. Then try `paste` again but with the clean files.

Comment: You are probably right.  I am leaving for the day but next week I will give that a whirl, I bet that will solve the problem.  Will let you know how it turns out.  Thanks!